# How to change embed message colour to white?

Tags: python, colors, discord, discord.py

So was coding a discord bot in python and I wanted to change the colour of an embed message to white.

```
white = discord.Color.from_rgb(255,255,255)
embed = discord.Embed(title = ":8ball:8ball", description = random.choice(responses), colour = white)
```

I tried using:

- colour = discord.Color.from_rgb(255,255,255)
- colour = 16777215

But the colour was dark grey like this:

[image]

How can I change the colour to white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution on some random github page:

colour = 0xeeffee

With this i was able to produce:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
white = 0xeeffee
@client.command(name = "eightball", description = "Asks the 8ball a question.", aliases = ["8ball","8b"])
async def eightball(ctx,*,question):
    responses = ("It is Certain.","It is decidedly so.","Without a doubt.","Yes definitely.","You may rely on it.","As I see it, yes.","Most likely.","Outlook good.","Yes.","Signs point to yes.","Reply hazy, try again.","Ask again later.","Better not tell you now.","Cannot predict now.","Concentrate and ask again.","Don't count on it.","My reply is no.","My sources say no.","Outlook not so good.","Very doubtful.")
    embed = discord.Embed(title = ":8ball:8ball", description = random.choice(responses), colour = white)    
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using hex codes instead of discord.Color, unless using one of the base colors. You can get a hex by dragging around here (https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-picker/) and then just copy the code given (ex. FFFFFF) and append 0x to the front (so it becomes 0xFFFFFF), and that should make the embed white! That also works for any color with a valid hex code. You can also use (https://www.rgbtohex.net/) to convert a rgb value into a hex code!

So in this case:

```py
white = 0xFFFFFF
embed = discord.Embed(title = ":8ball:8ball", description = random.choice(responses), colour = white)
```